# How to delete rows in a table based on this specific condition without mentioning the column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to clean several tables on my SQL Server database by deleting all rows where all the columns in the table have NULL values or are Blanks.

I know I can do it using CASE Statements or filtering the columns in my query.

Example:

```
Delete from [T1]

WHERE [col1] IS NULL OR [col1] = ''
AND [col2] IS NULL OR [col2] = ''
AND [col3] IS NULL OR [col3] = ''
```

It would be quite tedious to write the column names for each relevant table. I am looking for a single T-SQL query that would allow me to do so simply by replacing the table name in the query.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible, yes. Dynamic SQL is the solution.

Comment: *All* columns? Is there no primary key in the table? Besides, `''` isn't null, it's a very specific string value. You could use eg `CHECKSUM(*)` if you wanted to find rows with the same values, but in your case you're looking for rows with multiple combinations of NULLs and strings. You'll have to write a dynamic SQL query for this

Comment: How did the table end up with nulls anyway? And why are empty strings treated as nulls? It looks like there's a table design bug, perhaps an application bug as well, if empty strings are treated the same as nulls. You could prevent such values by using nullability constraints and possibly CHECK constraints as well

Comment: Also your example query is not going to perform as you intended without parentheses around each column's criteria

Comment: @Stu do you mean it should be like this: WHERE ([col1] IS NULL OR [col1] = '')
AND ([col2] IS NULL OR [col2] = '')
AND ([col3] IS NULL OR [col3] = '')

Comment: Yes because otherwise any `or` will have precedence

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not a complete answer or solution, but your `WHERE` clause could be somewhat simplified:

```sql
DELETE
FROM T1
WHERE COALESCE(col1, '') + COALESCE(col2, '') + COALESCE(col3, '') = '';
```

Comment: It hurts to see this but ... yes. I doubt the columns are indexed, so even a normal query would have to perform a full table scan. Perhaps `CONCAT_WS(col1,col2,...)` can be used as well as it ignores nulls

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Congratulations on +100K.  You should be getting a T-shirt and coffee mug soon.

Comment: Thanks. I'm vain enough that I actually googled for this yesterday. And found in meta there's at least 1 year backlog :D

Comment: It took about 1 year for me to receive the 250K goody bag.  By the time it arrived, I had lost interest in it `:-)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. Does your solution also take care of NULLS?

Comment: @user3115933 Yes, the calls to `COALESCE` will replace null with empty string.  So the where clause is basically saying if all columns are either null or empty string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I get the following error when running the codes: Error converting data type nvarchar to float. What could be causing this?

Comment: @user3115933 It means that some of your column are float, not text.  Your original question did not imply that you have columns of all types.  If so, then each column type might need separate logic.